# Why were the file date formats changed?

Tags: date

I just updated Ubuntu, expecting not to notice any major changes and when I tried to open a file I noticed that the dates were in a new format.  I'm American and I specified I wanted American English when I installed Ubuntu, why would somebody change the date format to be the one used in other countries?  This is was very confusing for me.

Comment: Did you want to change the date format back, or just complain about it? Because you can change it in Language Support -> Regional Formats.

Comment: That doesn't work, they have the wrong date format their as well.

Comment: What did you open the file with?

Comment: I used Audacity...

Answer (score 0):

Regarding why your date format was changed, this Ubuntu Forums thread entitled ["I upgraded, and now I have this error..."](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1946145) might be enlightening.  Here's the executive summary: operating systems are complicated beasts, and any process that promises to upgrade the OS automatically has a high likelihood of causing problems, because the process is huge and complicated, and impossible to test on every variation of hardware that people run Ubuntu on.  This problem is by no means unique to Ubuntu; once I ran a script that promised to upgrade a computer from Windows Vista to Windows 7, and it crashed and burned and left the system unusable.  (And that script was written by the maker of the computer, for just that model.)  I would think that a majority of experienced Ubuntu users don't bother with the automatic upgrade, but rather copy their personal files off (or use a separate partition for `/home`), wipe the Ubuntu partitions, and do a fresh install of the newer version.  That process is a pain, but it bypasses so many potential problems.

So now you know.  In your case the script probably ran into a problem before it got around to setting the date format to the way you had it before.  If your date format is the only thing that was messed up, then you're fairly lucky.  I have one computer that I've updated automatically about three times, and it wants to fire off three or four error reports every time it boots.